# Format maxLabel on axis differently than other labels

Tags: echarts

I am hoping to use a different format specifically for the top axis label on my y-axis. For example, if I have a percentage value axis, I would like to see the **%** symbol only on the top axis label, while the rest of the labels beneath it remain formatted as numbers without a symbol.

So far, I've been using the `formatter` option and have created a function that receives `value` and `index` per the ECharts docs. The example link below does what I need it to do, but does it for the bottom of the axis rather than the top. I need a way to use this same logic, but select the maximum index on the axis.

**Link to example in docs:**
https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.axisLabel.formatter

**Code from example in docs:**
The `if (index === 0)` is the logic I'm referring to

```js
// Use callback function; function parameters are axis index
formatter: function (value, index) {
    // Formatted to be month/day; display year only in the first label
    var date = new Date(value);
    var texts = [(date.getMonth() + 1), date.getDate()];
    if (index === 0) {
        texts.unshift(date.getYear());
    }
    return texts.join('/');
}
```

Here's what I've tried:

- I attempted to use the `index` argument to figure out the max index # in my dataset, but couldn't figure out how to do that given that the function is called once per value and includes only the data for that value.
- I tried passing `params` to the function since that's how `formatter` works in the `series` config, but it looks like that's not possible in the `axis` config
- One (unattractive) alternative is to use the y-axis `axisName` to display any symbols I want to have appended to the top label, and manually position it using `padding`. This probably wouldn't work because I'll also need to use the `axisName` separately from time to time.

**A Possible Hint**
This might not be possible yet, but at least behind the scenes I know ECharts is able to select the top label through the `showMaxLabel` option in `axisLabel`.

Is there a way to check if a label is the maximum label in the `formatter` function for an axis?